# How do I change my nexus wars builder skin?

Tags: starcraft-2

So I've been playing nexus wars for a while.  I've seen lots of people with different builders (other than SCV) how do I change my builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based off your number of wins. If you have 10 or more wins, type `-builder 2` into the in-game chat and hit enter. `-builder 2` gives you a Zergling and `-builder 3` gives you the Protoss builder. It goes up from there. More wins gives you more options.